# unorderable types: str() < tuple() when train pet detector by google object detection api

Tags: tensorflow, detection

I train　pet detector by google object detection api and get error as fellow：Does it mean sorted fun does not support the dict's key type is tuple and the object detection api still does not support python3?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1578, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1015, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "E:/Work/Lib/tensorflow/models/object_detection/train.py", line 198, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "E:/Work/Lib/tensorflow/models/object_detection/train.py", line 194, in main
    worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
  File "E:\Work\Lib\tensorflow\models\object_detection\trainer.py", line 184, in train
    data_augmentation_options)
  File "E:\Work\Lib\tensorflow\models\object_detection\trainer.py", line 77, in _create_input_queue
    prefetch_queue_capacity=prefetch_queue_capacity)
  File "E:\Work\Lib\tensorflow\models\object_detection\core\batcher.py", line 93, in __init__
    num_threads=num_batch_queue_threads)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py", line 919, in batch
    name=name)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py", line 697, in _batch
    tensor_list = _as_tensor_list(tensors)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py", line 385, in _as_tensor_list
    return [tensors[k] for k in sorted(tensors)]
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < tuple()
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I traced the issue down to a python 3 compat issue in TensorFlow. I have submitted a fix for it here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/11039